# onActivityResult not being called inside FragmentActivity that contains Android Map view fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, onactivityresult

I have a fragment activity that displays an Android V2 Map. Inside I also have a onActivityResult used to handle the intent Extras that needs to be passed from the calling activity

```
public class DisplayMap extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onCreate(arg0);

       setContentView(R.layout.map);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

       Log.v("TEST", "********************************************");
    }
}
```

Here is the code form the activity that calls it.

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.example.DisplayMap");
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
startActivityForResult(i, 2014);
```

But somehow the onActivityResult is not called inside.

Thanks in advance. 
Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onActivityResult() needs to be in the *calling* activity, it retrieves the result, as the name suggests.

To return a result from the called activity you'll need to use setResult() and finish that activity:

**called activity:**

```
Intent i = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```

with RESULT_OK being passed as the `resultCode` parameter to `onActivityResult()` and i as `intent`

**calling activity:**

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.example.DisplayMap");
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
```

and to receive the result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            // RESULT OK, take the returned extras from intent and use them
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean to pass parameters from the Calling activity to the called activity. Is the solution suggested to pass parameters from the called activity back to the calling activity.